# Is this okay to use double proxy-server setup? One on host and one in centainer

Tags: docker, nginx

One nginx server on host machine with renewable ssl certificate (via certbot). And another nginx server inside docker container. First one should redirect all traffic to the second one.

Currently I have one nginx service inside container and I connect certificates that stored on host to that server via volumes. But with this kind of setup I can't renew certificates automatically...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get and renew certificate at container and somehow share it with proxy server(mount any common method dir with certificates).

renew cert at container
reload nginx at container server
reload nginx at proxy server

its not a simple solution - you should monitor always if your proxy server lost mounted directory, but it looks like a solution.

Comment: I already use a solution that works with hops. Don't think that I will change it to the another hacky method (: